# AJAX call always giving error instead of results

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button in a view that is successfully calling into this javascript function that I've created (I've debugged into it successfully).

However, when it gets to the AJAX portion it always returns with my alert(error message).

I want the AJAX to direct my parameters to the ResultsController 's Index method.

```
var params =
    {
        state: "California",
        county: "Los Angeles County",
        city: "Los Angeles",
        lastname: "Doe", 
        firstname: "John"
    }
//^ Verified!  Params is populated successfully

$.ajax({
    url: '/Results/Index',
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function () {
        if (data) {
            alert('life is good');
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        // something
    },
    error: function () { alert('An error has occured. '); }
});
```

Here's the controller method header that I'm trying to reach (in the ResultsController)

```
public ActionResult Index(string state, string county, string city, string lastname, string firstname)
```

Comment: You can obtain useful debugging info from the network monitor for browser's developer console. It will allow you to examine the request and response headers.

Comment: try `data: params,` instead of `data: JSON.stringify(params),`

Comment: Certanly not a cause, but there is no `data` parameter for success callback. Also, are you sure there is no server-side errors on this call?

Comment: try error: function(xhr) {alert(xhr.responseText);} and see what's been returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success callback should have a parameter data. See following:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
        alert('life is good');
    }
},
```